# Akka Cluster Sharding - How to test

Tags: testing, akka-cluster

I want to test a function that at some point asks an EventSourcedBehaviorWithEnforcedReplies  using ClusterSharing

I prepare the ClusterSharding like:

```
  ClusterSharding.get(testKit.system()).init(
    Entity.of(
        ENTITY_TYPE_KEY,
        entityContext -> new Entity(entityContext.getEntityId())));
```

The function sends a command :

```
CompletionStage<ActorAnswer> promisedAnswer = sharding
    .entityRefFor(ENTITY_TYPE_KEY, identifier)
    .ask(CommandToExecute::new, ASK_TIMEOUT)
```

The CompletionStage never gets executed...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

After same research

1) check that in your application-test.conf

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = cluster
  }
}
```

2) Cluster needs to be created and join cluster (self join) - easiest that I found was programmatically

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.get(testKit.system());
cluster.manager().tell(Join.create(cluster.selfMember().address()));
```

3) Then we can talk about cluster sharding :)

```
  ClusterSharding.get(testKit.system()).init(
  clusterSharding.init(
    Entity.of(ENTITY_TYPE_KEY, entityContext -> new Entity(entityContext.getEntityId())));
```

Comment: How can we define entity actors mailbox and dispatcher in configuration level